# Thermostat swap

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, heating, cooling

While switching out thermostat I noticed only two wires instead of more Rh W to be specific. The new thermostat has no Rh only R and Rc on Wich I selected R. Heat turns on now but doesn't turn off at the desired temperature, it exceeds desire without regulation? Please help

Comment: What make and model is your thermostat, and can you post photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and the furnace ends please?

Comment: How far beyond the set point did you allow it to go some thermostats have offsets both electronic and mechanical. This value may need to be set or adjusted

Comment: Is this a) a simple dumb mechanical thermostat?  b) a programmable thermostat that takes batteries?  Or c) a smart thermostat with WiFi that recommends a C-wire?